# Do empty fields in structs consume memory?

Tags: go, memory, struct

I have a struct with fields:

```
type Measure struct {
    ID            int
    IndexName     string    
    IndexValue    int   
    Redistributed float64
    MyArray       []myObject
}
```

If I initialize my object with

```
measure := Measure{
   ID: 10,
   IndexName: "",
   IndexName: 0,
   Redistributed: 0
   MyArray: nil         
}
```

What should be my memory footprint? When I instantiate a struct with empty fields, do I use memory anyway?

I am pretty sure I am, but I just need a confirmation.

Comment: Yes. They are populated with their corresponding [zero values](https://tour.golang.org/basics/12), which are the same as any other value.

Comment: A minor nitpick: these fields are not empty, they are not explicitly assigned (and so automatically initialized to the zero values appropriate for the respective types of the fields). The need to not call them empty arises from the fact, in Go, it's possible to have _really empty_ value by using for it a type `struct{}` — an empty struct. Variables (and fields, and array/slice/map elements) of this type consume no storage space (except when padding issues for enclosing `struct`s come into play).

Comment: I don't think it's a minor nitpick at all, it's fundamental to the understanding of the question. **There is no such thing as an "empty" field or variable.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Structs have fixed sizes. How you initialize them doesn't matter, it requires the same amount of memory.

If memory would not be allocated for fields initialized with their zero values, assigning values later on would require memory allocation.

Here's a simple benchmark code to verify it:

```
type T struct {
    i int
    s string
    x []int
    a [10]int64
}

var x *T

func BenchmarkZero(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x = &T{}
    }
}

var xval = make([]int, 10)

func BenchmarkNonZero(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x = &T{
            i: 10,
            s: "gopher",
            x: xval,
            a: [10]int64{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
        }
    }
}
```

Running it with `go test -bench. -benchmem`, output is:

```
BenchmarkZero-4      16268067      69.6 ns/op    128 B/op    allocs/op
BenchmarkNonZero-4   13961296      75.8 ns/op    128 B/op    allocs/op
```

Both `BenchmarkZero()` and `BenchmarkNonZero()` performs a single allocation being 128 bytes, which is the size of `T` (`unsafe.Sizeof(T{})` returns 128). This size is on 64-bit architecture: 8 (`int`) + 16 (`string` header) + 24 (slice header) + 80 (`[10]int64` array size). No implicit padding is required in case of this struct, so this is its final size.

I purposefully used `xval` package level variable when providing a value for `T.x` to avoid having to allocate value for it in the benchmark (and to not mess with what's benchmarked).

Comment: To the OP, just to make things more clear, I hope: even when you assign the `MyArray` field a non-`nil` value (say, after calling `make([]myObject, 42)`), the struct value _itself_ would still consume the same amount of memory as it did before assignment—just that particular field, whose type (a slice) has _reference semantics_ — would reference a block of allocated memory, as opposed to referring to nothing when the field was containing the zero value for its type, `nil`. (A nitpick: `[]T` is a slice, not array; it's better to not use confusing terminology.)